# Faster optimize table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I have a 5TB+ MySQL database on RDS which I need to optimize. One particular table 1.5TB. We ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on this table in a separate RDS instance restored from a snapshot and the results were encouraging, but the command took 32 hours to run!

Is there a way to improve performance of the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` command? This table has 6 indexes other than the PK. I believe removing them will offer significant speedups. We plan to bump up the to the largest instance size RDS offers (r3.8xlarge) to help speed up the process. Are there any parameter groups I can tweak to improve the performance?

Comment: You are right DROP INDEXES OTHER THAN PK -> OPTMIZE -> CREATE ALL INDEXES always work much faster on InnoDB tables. Other solution - may be it time to split table? I would be and faster for now and faster forever if keep in table only active data + have WareHouse for reports, we use Redshift for example.

Comment: @a_vlad database sharding is something we're looking at, but the immediate concern is reclaiming free space on the RDS instance.

Comment: How much space did it reclaim?

Comment: @RickJames 1.5TB --> 140GB

Comment: Testing this on a new replica is almost certainly going to give you a deceptively *long* runtime, because of the first-touch penalty of new EBS volumes created from snapshots, which is what apparently happens when you create an RDS replica (except in Aurora, where master and replicas share the backing store).  Lacking access to the underlying virtual machine, you can't deliberately warm up the entire new volume the same way you can in EC2.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot whoa! I did not know about that. Super helpful, thanks

Comment: Sources -- RDS: ["Most of Amazon RDS uses Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volumes for database and log storage"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html) EBS: ["storage blocks on volumes that were restored from snapshots must be initialized (pulled down from Amazon S3 and written to the volume) before you can access the block. This preliminary action takes time and can cause a significant increase in the latency of an I/O operation the first time each block is accessed."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you `PARTITION` the table (on anything), and have no more than, say, 30 partitions, then you could `REBUILD` each partition in about 3% of the total time, possibly a lot faster due to the size.  (Possibly following it with a `ANALYZE PARTITION` would be beneficial.)

Do *not* use 'optimize partition', that erroneously optimizes the entire table.

So, if you get enough reclaimed space to be worth it, set up a cron or EVENT to reorg one partition each night forever.

If you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some important queries, I may be able to advise on how to gain some other benefit from the partitioning.

Comment: are you referring REBUILD Partition followed by ANALYZE Partitions?

Comment: @SQL.RK - Yes, thanks.  Changing `REORGANIZE` to `REBUILD`.

Comment: Yes. Rebuild Partitions helps to regain the storage. When you Optimize table, it will get locked till table level Optimization completes. But Rebuild Partition also locks the table but for smaller duration. This is much safer even in Production environments.